# Swagger bootstrap on Weblogic 12.2

Tags: java, jax-rs, weblogic, swagger, weblogic12c

I would like to use swagger on Weblogic but I do not know how to bootstrap it via Java.

There is no Spring dependency in the project, no web.xml. It is a simple JAX-RS project.

A request to http://localhost:7001/..../swagger.json produces the proper content but I need to connfigure Swagger's base package and other staff.

I have tried to use the following solution but it does not work:
public class SwaggerJaxrsConfig extends HttpServlet {

```
public class SwaggerConfig extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        System.out.println("hello!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("http://localhost:7001/.../resources/swagger.json");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("a.b.c");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

Any idea how to bootstrap Swagger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly I have figure the solution out:

The following code works fine on Weblogic 12.2.1:

```
package com.xxx.yyy.rest.swagger;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(
        name = "SwaggerBootstrapServlet",
        urlPatterns = { "/SwaggerBootstrapServlet" },
        loadOnStartup = 1,
        initParams = {
                @WebInitParam(name = "swagger.api.basepath", value = "http://...:7001/.../resources"),
                @WebInitParam(name = "api.version", value = "1.0"),
                @WebInitParam(name = "swagger.api.title", value = "... REST API"),
                @WebInitParam(name = "swagger.pretty.print", value = "true")
        }
)
public class SwaggerBootstrapServlet extends DefaultJaxrsConfig {
}
```